# The increment size of the sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is 1

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to configure the properties for postgreSQL Database in my first sprinboot application. But when I run this application I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.jrp.pma.dao.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.jrp.pma.entities.Project]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.jrp.pma.dao.EmployeeRepository defined in 
    ... 39 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.jrp.pma.dao.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.jrp.pma.entities.Project]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.jrp.pma.entities.Project]
    at 
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.jrp.pma.entities.Project]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [project_seq] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
    at 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at
```

PostgreSQL properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pma-springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

version=3.0.0

SQL Query:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS employee_seq;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
   employee_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('employee_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
   email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS project_seq;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project (
   project_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('project_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   stage VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project_employee (
   project_id BIGINT REFERENCES project, 
   employee_id BIGINT REFERENCES employee
);
```

Project.java

```java
@Entity
public class Project {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "project_seq")
   private Long projectId;
   ....
   ....
}
```

Employee.java:

```java
@Entity
public class Employee {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_seq")
   private long employeeId;
   ...
   ..
}
```

[image: PostgreSQL Database Strucutre]
[image: port]

Comment: your `@GeneratedValue` annotation might be the problem. Try another strategy.

Comment: It worked after changing @GeneratedValue to IDENTITY. Thank you. Do you know why SEQUENCE GeneratedValue is not working in this code?

Comment: Hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity) does not advise to use IDENTITY due to mess up extended persistence contexts (long conversations) and inability to batch INSERT statements for the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change @GeneeratedValue=AUTO or IDENTITY. If you found the solution please close this

Comment: I don't think that's the right approach, because it just switches to another generator strategy. Besides, SEQUENCE is usually considered best-practice, see e.g. https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-identifier-sequence/

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you should use the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation in conjunction with the `@GeneratedValue` annotation to explicitly specify the increment size of the `project_seq` sequence.

You can do it in this way:

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "project_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "project_seq", sequenceName = "project_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long projectId;
```

By default the `allocationSize` is 50.

Comment: Thank you Stemk. Even after using the @SequenceGenerator as you mentioned, it is throwing the same error

Comment: Did you do the same for the `Employee` entity?