# Spring Cloud Stream Schema Registry server DDL sequence requires increments of 50

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

We are in the process of upgrading our Spring Cloud Stream Schema Registry server to version 4.0.2. We persist our schemas in PostgreSQL and use Flyway to help us manage migrations.

I noticed that while creating integration tests using a PostgreSQL testcontainer, I couldn't get the tests to execute successfully without the following DDL in place:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE schema_repository_seq INCREMENT BY 50 START WITH 1;
```

I tried setting the increment value to 1, but without the increment value of 50, the following error is encountered during test execution:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.registry.model.Schema]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.registry.model.Schema]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.registry.model.Schema]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [schema_repository_SEQ] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
```

I am curious why the increment size of 50 was chosen. With the previous versions of the server, this requirement was not in place.

In addition, I don't see any reference to anything in the [Schema entity class](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/schema-registry/spring-cloud-stream-schema-registry-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/schema/registry/model/Schema.java) that indicates this value of 50 is being enforced. Where is this value of 50 being enforced from?

Comment: Is this something Postgres specific? I found a related thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62167887/the-increment-size-of-the-sequence-is-set-to-50-in-the-entity-mapping-while-th

Comment: This link explains what is happening I think: https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-on-db-generated/. As explained here, without a ```@GeneratedValue``` and ```@SequenceGenerator``` annotation on the ```Schema``` Entity class, it looks like the default allocation size of 50 is being used. You can see in the source code for ```jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator``` that the default ```allocationSize()``` value is 50.

Comment: Thanks! I created a new issue to track this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2766